# CSS <ul> bullet points will not work

Tags: html, css

I have two id's that I am using for a `<ul>` tag in my website. The id .a works and doesn't have any bullet points. The id .b does not work when I use 
list-style-type: square; tag. Basically, I want id .b to have bullet points and I don't want id .a to have bullet points. Both of them don't show any bullet points. My question is what am I doing wrong with my id .b because I want it to have bullet points and it doesn't.

I will post the section of the code below.

```css
#navbar             {   margin-right: auto;
                    margin-left: auto;}

.a                  {   list-style-type: none;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    overflow:0;
                    }

.b                  {   list-style-type: square;
                    text-align: center;
                    }
```

Here are my full `<li>` and `<ul>` html tags

```html
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="a">
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company Index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pageone.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pagetwo.html">Auctions</a><li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pagethree.html">Contact</a><li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pagefour.html">Pictures</a><li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my full CSS code

```css
#navbar             {   margin-right: auto;
                    margin-left: auto;}

.a                  {   list-style-type: none;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    overflow:0;
                    }

.b                  {   list-style-type: square;
                    text-align: center;
                    }


a:link, a:visited   {   display: block;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: white;
                    background-color: black;
                    padding: 6px;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    width: 120px;
                    }

a:hover, a:active   {   background-color: red;}

li                  {   display:inline-block; margin-right:15px;}

html                    {   background-color: #262626;}

body                    {   margin: auto;
                        margin-left: 199px;
                        margin-right: 185px;
                        text-align: center;
                        background-color: white;}
```

Comment: I don't see any `li` (list item) elements in the code you posted here.  Bullets would only appear in front of the list items.

Comment: It should work as you have it written, see this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/52e5Lsm5/  Is it possible you have some other bit of css thats overriding it?

Comment: Those are also classes you are using, not IDs

Comment: It does work, supposing you do actually have items in the lists.

Comment: Also, those are classes, not id's. If you remove the list-style-type from the second pice you should be fine.

Comment: I updated my post to show my <li>

Comment: There's nothing you've shown that would explain the problem you describe.

Comment: Should I have <ul id="a"> instead of <ul class="a">?

Comment: What do you mean sparky?  I posted my id's that are assigned with my <ul>. Do you want me to post my whole CSS code?

Comment: @PatrickHannagan, yes, please post your full css.  What you've provided so far works as you want it to.  class="a" items have no squares and class="b" items have squares.  You can verify that its working here: https://jsfiddle.net/52e5Lsm5/1/

Comment: @AdamKonieska I put the full CSS code on

Comment: @KeithV Ok thanks Kieth, what would my code look like then?

Comment: @PatrickHannagan your B items are getting the square, but its getting swallowed up by this line of css:  'li { display:inline-block; margin-right:15px; }'

You may need to be more specific with your css selectors to get it working, something like ul.a li { display:inline-block; margin-right:15px; } might achieve what youre trying to do, depending on your markup.

Comment: @AdamKonieska I created another li tag for the id .b. What should I change the in-line block to for my                                                             ul.b li  {display:inline-block; margin-right: 15px} tag

Comment: Also, do you really have spaces in your hrefs?

Comment: @MrLister on the actual website itself I have spacing between the links. On the code I have a space between a tag and the href if that is what you mean.

Comment: @PatrickHannagan I mean if you have filenames with spaces in them, you shouldn't put spaces in the references like "Hannagan Auction Company Index.html". To avoid problems, refer to them as "Hannagan%20Auction%20Company%20Index.html"

Comment: @PatrickHannagan you probably don't want any property set for display on ul.b.  It would help to see an example of your <li class="b"> markup.

Comment: @MrLister Oh ok Thank you, I will be sure to change that and keep that in mind for future use.

Comment: @AdamKonieska It works now Adam, thank you for your help. I was not specific enough in my code and my list was being swallowed up like you said. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @PatrickHannagan, awesome!  Glad you got it working. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class="b" list items are getting the square, but its getting swallowed up by this line of css: `li { display:inline-block; margin-right:15px; }`

You may need to be more specific with your css selectors to get it working, something like ul.a li { display:inline-block; margin-right:15px; } might achieve what you're trying to do, depending on your markup.

You haven't shared what your markup is for the class="b" items, but you can see its working in this JS fiddle with that change to the css:  https://jsfiddle.net/52e5Lsm5/5/

Answer (score 0):

This css should work:

```css
#navbar             {   margin-right: auto;
                    margin-left: auto;}

.a                  {   list-style-type: none;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    overflow:0;
                    }

.b                  {   list-style-type: bullets;
                    text-align: center;
                    }


a:link, a:visited   {   display: block;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: white;
                    background-color: black;
                    padding: 6px;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    width: 120px;
                    }

a:hover, a:active   {   background-color: red;}

li                  {   margin-right:15px;}

html                    {  background-color: #262626;}

body                    {   margin: auto;
                        margin-left: 199px;
                        margin-right: 185px;
                        text-align: center;
                        background-color: white;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="a">
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company Index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pageone.html">About</a><li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pagetwo.html">Auctions</a><li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pagethree.html">Contact</a><li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pagefour.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
  <ul class="b">
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company Index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pageone.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pagetwo.html">Auctions</a></li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pagethree.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="Hannagan Auction Company-pagefour.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```